# Laravel9 how to join two tables if one of many conditions is met

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have 2 tables, I want to gather all the coletes that have the same invoice_id as the invoices id  OR if the invoice_id = invoices storno_id

```
InvoicesID      Coletes.INVOICE_ID 
1                  1
                   1
                   1
```

But also

```
 Invoices.STORNO_ID      Coletes.INVOICE_ID
           1                        1
                                    1
                                    1
```

My query looks like this:

```
$data = DB::table('invoices')
->leftJoin('coletes','coletes.invoice_id','=','invoices.id')
->where('coletes.invoice_id','=',$id)
->orWhere('coletes.invoice_id','=','invoices.storno_id')
->get();
```

But it only returns the coletes with invoice_id = $id, and not also the ones with the same invoice_id as invoices,storno_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In traditional SQL queries, you can select from multiple tables like so `from invoices, coletes`. This can be done by using `DB::raw()` with the query builder. Then adding the join logic, as where logic instead.

```
DB::table(DB::raw('invoices, coletes'))
    ->where('coletes.invoice_id', 'invoices.id')
    ->where(function($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('coletes.invoice_id', $id)
            ->orWhere('coletes.invoice_id', 'invoices.storno_id')
    })->get();
```

Comment: Perfect, if it helped you please accept it as an answer to help others :)